# Find longest prefix that matches a certain condition in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to figure out a way to find out longest prefix of a string which matches a certain condition.

It is trivial to write a imperative method which does exactly that, but I am new to scala and wondering if there is an idiomatic scala (or functional) way to do that.

- Keep iterating through longest prefixes (mystring.take(mystring.size),..mystring.take(1)
- Apply a predicate on each of those substrings
- If a prefix matches a predicate, break the loop and return the longest prefix.

Comment: What have you tried? If it is trivial to write an imperative method, please write one (preferably in Scala of course).

Answer (score 1):

For example, this:

```
def predicate(str: String): Boolean = ???

val longest_matching: Option[String] = 
  Iterator(mystring.size, 0, -1) // iterator of lengths
    .map(mystring.take)          // take string prefix
    .find(predicate)             // find first matching entry

longest_matching.fold {
  println("No matching prefix")
} { prefix =>
  println("Longest matching prefix: " + prefix)
}
```

You can take full advantage of the Scala standard library by using [`inits`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString@inits:Iterator[Repr]):

```
val longest_matching = mystring.inits.find(predicate)
```